# How can I integrate a function which prints out a list, using the trapezium rule

Tags: python

I want to integrate the function func(s) which gives out a list when given a value of s.

```
def func(s):
    for i in range(1, 100):
        p = i * 2 + s * 2
        yield p

def trap0 (f,lowerl,upperl,n):
    h = float (upperl-lowerl)/n
    s =(list(f(lowerl))+list(f(upperl)))/2
    for i in range (1,n):
        s = s+f(lowerl+i*h)
    return s * -h

lists1=[]

lists1.append(trap0(func,-1,9,50))
print lists1
```

I keep getting 
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'generator' and 'generator'. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Since `func` returns a generator, you need to convert what it returns to a list:

```
def trap0 (f,lowerl,upperl,n):
    h = float (upperl-lowerl)/n
    s =(list(f(lowerl)) + list(f(upperl)))/2
    for i in range (1,n):
        s = s + list(f(lowerl+i*h))
    return s * -h
```

Comment: I have changed the func to return a list `def func(s):
    l = []
    for i in range(1, 100):
        l.append(i*2+s*2)
    return l` but i still get the error `unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'` for the line `s =(f(lowerl)+f(upperl))/2`

Comment: In `func` you say `yield p`.  That makes `func` a generator function.

Comment: I have changed the function to return a list `def func(s):
    l = []
    for i in range(1,10):
        l.append(i*2+s*2)
    return l
print (func(10))

def trap0 (f,lowerl,upperl,n):
    h = float (upperl-lowerl)/n
    s =(list(f(lowerl)) + list(f(upperl)/2))
    for i in range (1,n):
        s = s + list(f(lowerl+i*h))
    return s * -h

lists1=[]

lists1.append(trap0(func,-1,9,50))` but i still keep on getting the error `unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'` can you help me out with this

Comment: It's a little hard to read in a comment.  Would you mind putting it on http://pastebin.com/ or on https://ideone.com/?

Comment: You can't divide a list by two.  What is it you are trying to accomplish with that?

Comment: well it is a part of the trapezium rule where we have to divide the sum of function with the upper range value and lower range value by 2. I tried to multiply it with instead of 0.5 but realized that we can multiply a list by float, so now I am kind of stuck on what to do.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the Trapezium Rule, but mathematics doesn't usually use things like lists or tuples.  Are you sure `func()` is returning the right thing?

Comment: Yes, the `func()` is supposed to return a list of values.

Comment: Let's say `func(...) + func(...)` is `[3, 4, 6, 2]`.  What do you expect the outcome of division by two to be?

Comment: looking at it now, it seems that it wouldn't work. but at the same time I can not multiply the list by a float,so is there any other way around it ?

Comment: That really depends on what you want to do.  If the outcome of the addition of the two functions is `[3, 4, 6, 2]`, what do you want to get from that?

Comment: well i am basically integrating the function func(s), so according to the trapezium rule we have to multiply the list by h/2, where h is (upper limit- lower limit)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107085/discussion-between-zondo-and-p-kumar).